# CasperJS counts each assertion as a Test... That's not right! How to group these?

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing, casperjs

I'm writing integration tests with CasperJS, but the output has an issue, IMO: it counts each assertion as a test, instead of allowing for tests to have multiple assertions in them (like JUnit, Nunit, etc).

Is there a way to tell Casper that each assertion is actually not a test, but just an assertion?

For example:

```
casper.test.begin("This is my first test", 3, function(test) {
  test.assert(true);
  test.assert(true);
  test.assert(true);
  test.done();
});

casper.test.begin("This is my second test", 3, function(test) {
  test.assert(true);
  test.assert(true);
  test.assert(true);
  test.done();
});
```

This will yield this output:

```
# This is my first test
PASS Subject is strictly true
PASS Subject is strictly true
PASS Subject is strictly true
# This is my second test
PASS Subject is strictly true
PASS Subject is strictly true
PASS Subject is strictly true
PASS 6 tests executed in 0.028s, 6 passed, 0 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

When I report this on TeamCity, it shows 6 tests passed, which is not true. I have just two tests, not six. Each test makes 3 assertions.

Instead, I'd expect to see the following output:

```
PASS This is my first test
  - Subject is strictly true
  - Subject is strictly true
  - Subject is strictly true
PASS This is my second test
  - Subject is strictly true
  - Subject is strictly true
  - Subject is strictly true
PASS 2 tests executed in 0.028s, 2 passed, 0 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

Ideally tests would be grouped by suites according to the file they come from, and each `test.begin` would signify exactly that: a new test. Having each assertion counting as a test makes no sense at all.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem seems to be. Please show an example output and what you would expect. Also, please look into the [`--xunit=<filename>` option](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html).

Comment: @Ar Thanks for the reply, I have updated my question. I'm indeed using --xunit. I wonder if what I need could be accomplish wrapping Casper into another tool that accounts for tests correctly? Assertion != Test

Comment: @ArtjomB., he's trying to run a group of assertions and consider that grouping as 1 test. As he explained, that's how other test suites behave. I have the same issue, I'm looking into a solution now. Edy, if you've found a solution (using CasperJS), please share :-)